# Convert MySQL create table query to H2 syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, h2, ddl

I have a small MySQL statement (two actually) to create a table:

```
# --- !Ups

create table `user` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `first_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `last_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `mobile` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `email` TEXT NOT NULL
)

# --- !Downs
drop table `user`
```

and I would like to convert both to H2 syntax. I've never touched H2 before, and [the documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table) is not very clean

I assume the drop query would be:

```
DROP TABLE USER
```

right? what about the create query?

Comment: You know that the documentation you linked includes examples, right?

Comment: `psql` is the command line client for Postgres. The code you haven shown is clearly for MySQL.

Comment: sorry, I was thinking about MySQL but somehow I wrote Postgres/psql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Intellij found the solution:

```
# --- !Ups
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.USER
(
  ID         BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  FIRST TEXT                              NOT NULL,
  LAST  TEXT                              NOT NULL,
  MOBILE     BIGINT                            NOT NULL,
  EMAIL      TEXT                              NOT NULL
);

# --- !Downs
DROP TABLE PUBLIC.USER
```

Comment: would you share info how did you do it?